# index page in root folder and index page in subfolder error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have site xyz.com with index.php page And there is a subfolder in rootfolder.
e.g. folder viz. "audio" which contains index.php and other pages.

Now problem is When I opened www.xyz.com/audio it opens but when i navigate in this audio folder through navigation menu and try to return to audio/index.php  by clicking link in navigation bar in audio folder, it brings me to www.xyz.com/index.php instead of www.xyz.com/audio/index.php. But other pages navigation in audio folder works perfectly.

I have used .htaccess in root folder and in audio folder too with following rules (Used to remove file extension). Is it creating this error ? Or any other thing? I got stucked..

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php|html)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index([/.]|$) /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: what exactly does the link in the audio folder navigation bar point to?

Comment: Can you comment out 2nd `R=302` rule and retest. Also post your `/audio/.htaccess` file.

Comment: .htaccess in audio folder is same as above

Comment: @anubhava , .htaccess in audio folder is same as above

Comment: Did you comment out 2nd `R=302` rule from both .htaccess and retested as I suggested?

Comment: @anubhava yes, i tried comment out r=302 rule using #, but it didn't worked. Till After clicking on Home Page in navigation menu in audio folder gets redirected to www.xya.com/index.php instead of www.xyz.com/audio/index.php (on mousehover on home page link, www.xyz.com/audio/index.php is seen in left bottom corner of browser, but gets redirected to www.xyz.com/index.php after clicking home link)